# Google Script to auto switch sheet/tabs with conditional

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having difficult to write a gscript to change between tabs, no matter what I do always "Janeiro" is the tab filled with the information :/ is there something wrong with conditional code?

```
function EntradaDespesa() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = spreadsheet.getRange("Entrada!B3:I3");
  var mes = spreadsheet.getRange('Entrada!J3')

//Janeiro
  if(mes==1){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Janeiro").activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('Janeiro!B29').activate();

    var col = spreadsheet.getRange('Janeiro!B29:B117');
    var values = col.getValues();
    var ct = 0;
    while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
   }
   var range = spreadsheet.getRange(ct+29,2);
   spreadsheet.setActiveRange(range);

    source.copyTo (spreadsheet.setActiveRange(range), {contentsOnly: true});
    source.clear ();
  }


//Fevereiro  
  else if(mes==2){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Fevereiro").activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('Fevereiro!B29').activate();

    var col = spreadsheet.getRange('Fevereiro!B29:B117');
    var values = col.getValues();
    var ct = 0;
    while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
      ct++;
    }
    var range = spreadsheet.getRange(ct+29,2);
    spreadsheet.setActiveRange(range);

    source.copyTo (spreadsheet.setActiveRange(range), {contentsOnly: true});
    source.clear ();
  }

    Browser.msgBox("Despesa computada!");
   }
```

Comment: Range is a object. You'd need value: `range.getValue()`

Comment: Sorry, but where? ^^

Comment: `var mes = spreadsheet.getRange('Entrada!J3')`

Comment: It didn't work :/ It seems change betweens tabs is unfunctional in any way that I change the code

Comment: What have you done to debug it?

Comment: The code "works", just don't change the tab

Answer (score 0):

The variable `spreadsheet` is declared at the top of the code and you are using it by activating several Sheets. I'm not sure if that is supposed to work as you expect, but it's a much better option to declare two variables with the Sheets and use them separately:

```
function EntradaDespesa() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = spreadsheet.getRange("Entrada!B3:I3");

  var janeiroSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Janeiro');
  var fevereiroSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Fevereiro');
```

---

Remove the lines

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Janeiro").activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('Janeiro!B29').activate();
```

Since it's not necessary to activate the Sheets each time you use them. The same for the second month.

---

Then, instead of

```
 var range = spreadsheet.getRange(ct+29,2);
   spreadsheet.setActiveRange(range);
```

You can do

```
var range = janeiroSheet.getRange(ct+29,2);
```

and the same for fevereiro. You don't need to activate the ranges either.

---

To write the values into the desired Sheet, use
`janeiroSheet.getRange(range).setValues(col)`

You should read the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script) and try to do it to learn more about how to use these methods.

**References**

- [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Sheet Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)